# Selenium: How do I get the src of an image?

Tags: image, selenium

I'm using Selenium (within PHPUnit) to test my web application. I would like to test whether a certain image which is present on the page really exists. More precisely, whether the image url returns 404 or not. In order to test that, I need to get the image url. Given the image locator, How do I get the value of its src attribute (its url)?

Answer (score 34):

Assuming that you have an image in a WebElement (lets say img), in Java world you can retrieve the link below

**Editing the answer to clarify.**
By Java world I mean Selenium 2.0 Java bindings. In Selenium 2.0 (of course if you are using webdriver) has a class called WebElement representing elements on the page. getAttribute is a selenium Method in Java binding.

```
String url = "http://www.my.website.com";
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(url);
WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
String src = img.getAttribute("src");
```

Perhaps there is something similar in PHPUnit

Comment: I'm not in Java world, but in Selenium world. In Selenium world I don't have an object which represents the element. So I cannot get the img attributes that easily.

Comment: By Java world I meant Selenium 2.0 bindings in Java. See my edited answer.

Comment: Assuming this is the OP's accepted answer...? It's been 8 years so far.

Answer (score 4):

Below code will help you to get the list of all images and their URLs.
You can also use ***script*** instead on ***img*** to get the list of javascript files.

```
    package seleniumlinkpackage;

    import java.util.List;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class xmenfirstclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String url = "Paste Your URL here";
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);

        List links=driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
    // this will display list of all images exist on page
        for(WebElement ele:links){
            System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("src"));
        }

            //Wait for 5 Sec
            Thread.sleep(5);

            // Close the driver
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'getAttribute' with XPath to get an image src (or any other attribute:  alt, title, width, etc.)

```
selenium.getAttribute("//img/@src");
```

Answer (score 2):

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img")).getAttribute("src")

Answer (score 0):

If You are you using any PHP webdriver like [facebook/phpwebdiver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver), then it will solve your problem very easily.

Example :

1) Create a wedriver object:

```
public function setUp()
{
parent::setUp();
$web_driver = new WebDriver();
$element = $web_driver->session();
}
```

With this `$element` variable you can easily access any HTML attribute with the following line:

```
$element->element('xpath', '//*[@id="logo"]')->attribute('src');
```

This will return you the value of `src` attibute. You can use this line to get any attribute like class, id, title, alt, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use XPath. For PHPUnit and Selenium the Syntax for getting the src attribute of an image is:

```
$imageUrl = $this->getAttribute("//img/@src");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

> storeAttribute

And at the target place u have to mention like this

> //img[@src='imagename.png']@src.

And store that in a variable lets say

> img

Now verify that by using

> verifyAttribute

eg:command:

> verifyAttribute

target:

> //img[@src='imagename.png']@src

value:

> ${img}

Answer (score 0):

Well, in chrome one can write code in java to get the list of image src

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class imageUrl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                //Create Driver-object for chrome browser
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","//Users//admin//Desktop//chromedriver");
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

                //get the page
                driver.get("https://jet.com/");

                // this will find the elements by tag name. Don't forget to write "WebElement" after List.
                //or else it will give an error on the for loop

                List<WebElement>links=driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));

                // this will display list of all images exist on page
                for(WebElement ele:links){
                    System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("src"));
                }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imagesrc =document.DocumentNode.ChildNodes["html"].QuerySelector("image selector").Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the value of the *`src`* attribute of the `<img>` element you need to locate the element first and then use *`getAttribute()`* method to retrieve the attribute value as follows:

```
String src = driver.findElement(By.id("imageID")).getAttribute("src");
```

---

To print the value within the console:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("imageID")).getAttribute("src"));
```

---

Incase the `<img>` element is dynamically loaded you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("imageID"))).getAttribute("src"));
```

Answer (score -3):

use xPath, for example

```
//img[@src='The image src']
```

but unfortunately i am not sure that it is a good way to test if image was loaded

Comment: I didn't ask "how to retrieve an image by its src". I've asked "given the image, how to retrieve its src". I already have the image, but I don't know its src. Its src is what I need to get.