# Checking not loaded images

Tags: java, html, selenium

I'm so new in Selenium need help. I'm trying to get all image src in the page to check if there is not loaded image in the page. How can I check the images src? Can I check with "null"? Here is my code and of course there are mistakes. Also I checked some links for this issue, but didn't solve my problems for example this link: [Selenium: How do I get the src of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245013/selenium-how-do-i-get-the-src-of-an-image)

Do you know docs for the selenium selectors for learning?

```
  List<String>srcLinks = null;  
    List<WebElement> srcClass=driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
       for (WebElement src : srcClass) {
              srcLinks.add(src.getAttribute("src"));
               System.out.println(src);
           }
          for(int i=0;i<srcLinks.size();i++) {
              if(srcLinks.get(i).contains(null)) {
                  System.out.println("null img src found");
              }
      }
```

Also here is the HTML code for src:

```
<img class="bigBoutiqueImage lazy-load-trigger loaded"
 **src="https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com//Assets/ProductImages/OA/CampaignVisual/OriginalBoutiqueImages/12640/4pu3yjc3_11_new.jpg"** 
data-original="https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com//Assets/ProductImages/OA/CampaignVisual/OriginalBoutiqueImages/12640/4pu3yjc3_11_new.jpg" 
title="Twigy - Yılbaşı Özel"
 onerror="this.src='/Resources/images/bigBoutiquePlaceHolder.png'" 
alt="Twigy - Yılbaşı Özel">
```

Comment: what did you get from your code above? `System.out.println(src);`
using debugger to find out might help

Comment: I tried to print just to see images src.

Comment: what is the result? is it the html code above?

Comment: My code result returns null pointer error.Im trying the get src from html

Comment: your code return NPE because of this line `srcLinks.add(src.getAttribute("src"));` the list `srcLinks` have not initialized yet

Answer (score 1):

To print the **`src`** attributes of the `images` you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> srcClass = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
for (WebElement src : srcClass)
    System.out.println(src.getAttribute("src"));
```