# Selenium Webdriver wait Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to put selenium web driver wait, but always I am getting an exception "

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: mobileNo (tried for 20 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)".

I increased seconds to 100, then also getting the same problem, my id is correct.

```
    WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
    d.get("http://myurlOne");
    WebElement username = d.findElement(By.id("username_id"));          
    username.sendKeys("123");
    WebElement password = d.findElement(By.id("password_id"));
    password.sendKeys("123");
    d.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
    System.out.println("logged in successfully");
    d.get("http://navigatedurl");
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)d;  
    System.out.println("navigated to new page"); 
    WebDriverWait wait__mob = new WebDriverWait(d, 20);
    try {
        System.out.println("Start"+new Date());
        wait__mob .pollingEvery(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("mobileNo")));
        d.findElement(By.id("mobileNo")).sendKeys("99999999999);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Div code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-xs-5 control-label" for="mobileNo">Mobile No.</label>
     <div class="col-xs-6 leftpadding-none">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control k-input" id="mobileNo" 
       name="inputmobileNo" placeholder="" maxlength="10"> <!--required 
       pattern="\d{10}" validationMessage="Mobile No. is Required"-->
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the html of the page ? Is it the REAL div you need to check ?

Comment: You are getting exceptions because you haven't handled the exceptions properly and element is not locating after 20 seconds.

Comment: Its real div..i checked dat

Comment: yes element is not located after 20 seconds,i tried 100 seconds also,den also getting same ..

Comment: check if it inside a frame?

Comment: <input type="tel" class="form_input" id="mobileNo" name="mobileNo" placeholder="" maxlength="10">

Comment: Nvm I'm dumb. Did you made sure the element IS visible in your page ?

Comment: yes..its milli seconds only

Comment: (tried for 20 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)

Comment: It may be a scrolling problem. Selenium check if the element is visible on the screen he's given. Check for the window size, and whether the element is out of bounds.

Comment: f i give Thread.sleep(20)..Its working ..but webdriver wait not working

Comment: Did you check for presence of element first ? It is even present ? And check for frame too ? element might be inside a frame, and your webdriver is not able to see that

Comment: its outside frame only,and the thing is some time its identify the element,but most of times not

Comment: You are Using Java Selenium Binding, not Ruby binding! Said that why did you include `watir`?

Comment: i didnt understand what you commented..in java selenium cant we use wait?

Comment: In my case we not using frame,the element is inside div only

Comment: Update the question with relevant _HTML_

Comment: pls check updated code

Comment: can any one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *Java Docs* of [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) Class if you want to change the *Polling Interval* you need to change it in the *constructor* as the constructor is as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)

Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered (thrown) by default in the 'until' condition, and immediately propagate all others.
```

Moving forward as you are trying to invoke `sendKeys()` on the element you need to invoke the `ExpectedConditions` method [elementToBeClickable](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-).

So your code will be :

```
WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
d.get("http://myurlOne");
WebElement username = d.findElement(By.id("username_id"));          
username.sendKeys("123");
WebElement password = d.findElement(By.id("password_id"));
password.sendKeys("123");
d.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
System.out.println("logged in successfully");
d.get("http://navigatedurl");
System.out.println("navigated to new page"); 
WebDriverWait wait__mob = new WebDriverWait(d, 20);
try {
    System.out.println("Start"+new Date());
    wait__mob.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-group']//label[contains(.,'Mobile No.')]//following::div[1]/input[@class='form-control k-input' and @id='mobileNo' and @type='tel']"))).sendKeys("9999999999);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply,i tried ur code.but first time its worked and from second time its not working "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@class='form-control k-input' and @id='mobileNo'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)"

Comment: i am not using any frames,only div..is could be reason?and when i try element visible test,some times element not visible,i think element appear after driver runs

Comment: still same erro..org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@class='form-control k-input' and @id='mobileNo'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 100 milliseconds interval)

Comment: am not using frame.its full div only.we not using frame

Comment: <head><body><div>ELEMENT</div></body></head>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168631/discussion-between-learner-and-debanjanb).