# How can I access elements from a page if there is no frame tag using Selenium Webdriver wait?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hai i am trying to use webdriver in selenium test.but I can't find any element .always getting element not found exception.i tried,name,id,xpath everything..i am not using frames in my project, if we not using the frame or iframe cant we access elements inside div?in my case there are no frame tags.am giving example structure of my code.pls help

java code

```
    WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
         d.get("http://myurlOne");
       WebElement username = d.findElement(By.id("username_id"));          
       username.sendKeys("123");
       WebElement password = d.findElement(By.id("password_id"));
       password.sendKeys("123");
       d.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
        System.out.println("logged in successfully");
       d.get("http://navigatedurl");
       JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)d;  
        System.out.println("navigated to new page"); 
      WebDriverWait wait__mob = new WebDriverWait(d, 20);
        try {
    System.out.println("Start"+new Date());
                            WebDriverWait wait__mob = new WebDriverWait(d, 20);
try {
    System.out.println("Start"+new Date());
    wait__mob .pollingEvery(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("mobileNo")));
    d.findElement(By.id("mobileNo")).sendKeys("99999999999);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Html code

```
<html>
<body>
  <form class="formVal">
     <fieldset class="col-sm-9 col-md-12 leftpadding-none">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-5 control-label" 
         for="inputconsumerName">Consumer Name</label>
           <div class="col-xs-6 leftpadding-none">
              <input type="inputconsumerName" class="form-control k-input" 
              id="inputconsumerName" placeholder="" >
       </div>
           <div class="col-xs-1 leftpadding-none"> <a href=".loyalty" data- 
            toggle="tab" class="add-consumer"><span class="glyphicon 
              glyphicon-plus"></span></a> </div>
       </div>
     <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-5 control-label" for="inputmobileNo">Mobile 
       No.</label>
           <div class="col-xs-6 leftpadding-none">
              <input type="inputmobileNo" class="form-control k-input" 
              id="mobileNo" placeholder="" >
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group bottommargin-none">
           <label class="col-xs-5 control-label" for="inputOtherNo">OtherNo. 
         </label>
           <div class="col-xs-6 leftpadding-none">
              <input type="otherNo" class="form-control k-input" 
                 id="otherNo" placeholder="">
           </div>
        </div>
     </fieldset>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This only your HTML, can you add the code you've tried?

Comment: Which element are you trying to access?

Comment: this is just dummy html code,my question is if there is no frame or frame tag can i access element?

Comment: 1. yes you can access the element if there is no frame present in your DOM. 
2. If there is Frame present in the DOM then first switch to the frame and then access the element

Comment: pls check my old question..still am faceing problem...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730024/selenium-webdriver-wait-expected-condition-failed-waiting-for-visibility-of-ele?noredirect=1#comment86506474_49730024

Comment: Could you please provide the piece of code which you are using .. so that it will be very much clear

Comment: pls check updated code