# Get href attribute of an element of a web page using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this, but it returns the URL of the web page. I want the "href" in a text string.

```java
PATH_DATA = //[@id="vvp-product-details-modal--product-title"][@class="a-link-normal"]
WebElement myData = driver.findElement(By.xpath(PATH_DATA));
String url = myData.getAttribute("href")
```

It returns the URL of the web page. I want the "href" in a text string.

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: It is the first code of code syntactically correct?

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading (thus top search engine hits may lead to here (e.g. for "`href attribute Selenium`")). If the element reference (`myData` in the example) is ***already the correct one***, then `getAttribute` works just fine ([`getAttribute("href")` in Java](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#tabs-10-1), `get_attribute("href")` in Python, `GetAttribute("href")` in C#, `attribute("href")` in Ruby, `getAttribute("href")` in JavaScript, and `getAttribute("href")` in [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))...).

Comment: Or in other words, if the element reference is already the correct one, then trying to use CSS or XPath selectors just to get an attribute ("href" in this case) of an element is way too complicated (and unnecessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *`href`* attribute you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```java
  System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.a-link-normal#vvp-product-details-modal--product-title")).getAttribute("href"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```java
  System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-link-normal' and @id='vvp-product-details-modal--product-title']")).getAttribute("href"));
  ```

---

Ideally, to extract the the value of the *`href`* attribute, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getText()`:

  ```java
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.a-link-normal#vvp-product-details-modal--product-title"))).getAttribute("href"));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```java
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-link-normal' and @id='vvp-product-details-modal--product-title']"))).getAttribute("href"));
  ```

Comment: Thanks. It helps me!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is your best bet:

```java
href = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('#vvp-product-details-modal--product-title')?.href")
```