# Find a table cell and then find the corresponding row cell using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, siblings

Using Selenium/Java, I have a table where I need to find the country *Austria*, and then determine which Company is in that country. I found the xPath:

```
//td[.='Austria']
```

to Austria in the table, but is there a better way to use cells then move two cells to the left to find the Company name (Ernest Handel? Is there a better solution?

The table is at: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

To print the Company i.e. ***Ernst Handel*** associated with the country ***Austria*** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71148873/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *xpath* and *`preceding`*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
  System.out.println(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[.='Austria']//preceding::td[2]"))).getText());
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`preceding-sibling`*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
  System.out.println(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[.='Austria']//preceding-sibling::td[2]"))).getText());
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Ernst Handel
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Another XPath strategy is to select the first cell from the row whose third cell is 'Austria' (assuming you know that column 3 contains country names and column 1 contains company names):

```xml
//tr[td[3]='Austria']/td[1]
```