# Selenium fetching Integer value from a TD

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<td class="v-grid-cell numerical" style="height: 22px; width: 94px;" colspan="1">32942025</td>
```

This is my html code relevant to the question. I want to fetch that numeric value 32942025 and validate it with the output of a query I have fired.

I have been using `getText()` to extract this value but the `getText()` is not returning anything.

Can anyone please provide me a solution to this?

Note that this integer value is not inside an input field but it is displayed in a td class

Answer (score 0):

To print the text ***32942025*** from the `<td>` you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.v-grid-cell.numerical")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='v-grid-cell numerical']")).getText());
  ```

---

Ideally, to extract the text ***32942025***, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("td.v-grid-cell.numerical"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[@class='v-grid-cell numerical']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```