# How to identify element using ClassName and its Value using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

HTML:

```
<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-grid-xs-12 karutaNameNam css-1uqhpru">Super Heros</div>
```

How to select the element using class = karutaNameNam and its Value = "Super Heros".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the element with text as ***Super Heros*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='MuiGrid-root'][class*='karutaNameNam']"));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'karutaNameNam') and text()='Super Heros']"));
  ```

---

Ideally to identify the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [visibilityOfElementLocated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[class*='MuiGrid-root'][class*='karutaNameNam']][value='emptyAssembly']")));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'karutaNameNam') and text()='Super Heros']")));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

We can use dot[.] before class name inside 'cssSelector' for using className inside 'findElement' method

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('.MuiGrid-root.MuiGrid-grid-xs-12.karutaNameNam.css-1uqhpru'));

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('.karutaNameNam'));
```