# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status error while clicking using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am using Selenium with Java in Eclipse and I am getting these error very often  before I was getting error due to loading status now another.

Scenario: after opening the Website page there are several click that are supposed to happen and every time it is stuck on different stages

Traceback:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'AWAIS-PC', ip: '192.168.1.62', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [379a531d077c5128f9ab7816b39e5bdd, clickElement {id=6b67a9d0-7b57-4279-a7e4-b1e917a94925}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 103.0.5060.114, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd7..., userDataDir: C:\Users\WRP\AppData\Local\...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61026}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:61026/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.114, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (379a531d077c5128f9ab7816b39e5bdd)] -> css selector: button[class='CartTotal-secureCheckout'] span]
Session ID: 379a531d077c5128f9ab7816b39e5bdd
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:257)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:78)
    at First_Test.Practice_First.main(Practice_First.java:125)
```

Code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait waits = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//Thread.sleep(3000);
//  String originalWindow=  driver.getWindowHandle();
// Thread.sleep(5000);
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("wzrk-cancel")));
//waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#wzrk-cancel")));
driver.findElement(By.id("wzrk-cancel")).click();

// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='wzrk-cancel']")).click();
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/men']")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/men']")).click();

JavascriptExecutor Js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Js1.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,2500)");

waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton']")));
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Hibiscus Camo Arch Logo T-shirt in Cotton']")).click();

waits.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[title='Blue']")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[title='Blue']")).click();

//waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@title='Blue']")));
// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Blue']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Select-control']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='XL']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-cy^='addToBagButton']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[class='Select-control']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Select-control']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='L']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-cy^='addToBagButton']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
// waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[class^='Select-control']")));

waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='GO TO BAG']")));
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='GO TO BAG']")).click();

// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Secure Checkout']")).click();
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button[class='CartTotal-secureCheckout'] span")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='CartTotal-secureCheckout'] span")).click();
//  Thread.sleep(2000);
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".Map-enterAddressManuallyButton")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Map-enterAddressManuallyButton")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='regionId']//div[@class='Select Dropdown has-value is-searchable Select--single']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Ajman']")).click();
```

Comment: button[class='CartTotal-secureCheckout'] span] seems to be the issue here so this line driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='CartTotal-secureCheckout'] span")).click(); will need debugging. You waited for visibility but not clickability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *@ArundeepChohan* mentioned in his [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004935/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error#comment128942955_73004935) ideally to click on any ***clickable*** element instead of [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
WebDriverWait waits = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
waits.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[class='CartTotal-secureCheckout'] span")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='CartTotal-secureCheckout'] span")).click();
```

In a single line:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[class='CartTotal-secureCheckout'] span"))).click();
```