# How to locate WebElement in Oracle OTBI using Selenium

Tags: javascript, oracle, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm working on automating the scheduling of some reports. I've gotten as far as opening the report, but Selenium can't locate the 'Gear' icon. Below is the HTML of the element:

```
<a id="reportViewMenu" title="Actions" class="imageButton1L" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menu" style="display: inline;"><span class="ariaLabel">Actions</span><img style="vertical-align:text-bottom;" src="/xmlpserver/static/v20220415.1218/theme/alta/images/toolbar/popupmenu_ena.png" alt="" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='/xmlpserver/static/v20220415.1218/theme/alta/images/toolbar/popupmenu_ovr.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/xmlpserver/static/v20220415.1218/theme/alta/images/toolbar/popupmenu_ena.png'" onmousedown="this.src='/xmlpserver/static/v20220415.1218/theme/alta/images/toolbar/popupmenu_dwn.png'"></a>
```

Here is my latest attempt at locating the element using Java:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("'/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a[2]'"))).click();
```

I've tried using relative xpath (using the attribute with ID, Title, and Class), cssSelector, and ID. Absolutely stuck on this so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled dynamic element.

To click on the element instead of [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a#reportViewMenu[title='Actions'] span.ariaLabel +img"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@id='reportViewMenu' and @title='Actions']//span[@class='ariaLabel' and text()='Actions']//following::img[1]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still getting the same error using both of your techniques. Do you have any other suggestions I should look into? I've never worked with Selenium and was given this task, so am def a huge noob.

Answer (score 0):

Using @undidected Selenium's xpath and

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

I was able to locate the element