# How to get the duration of a youtube video in Sselenium+Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, youtube, css-selectors

It's my code:

```
@Test
    public void Task4Test(){
        DriverFactory driverFactory = new DriverFactory();
        WebDriver webDriver = driverFactory.initDriver();
        webDriver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
        webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='button']//*[contains(text(), 'Zaakceptuj wszystko')]")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//*[@id='video-title'])[1]")));
        String firstVideoTitle = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='video-title'])[1]")).getText();
        System.out.println(firstVideoTitle);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//ytd-channel-name[@id='channel-name']" +
                "/div/div/yt-formatted-string/a)[1]")));
        String firstVideoChannel = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("(//ytd-channel-name[@id='channel-name']" +
                "/div/div/yt-formatted-string/a)[1]")).getText();
        System.out.println(firstVideoChannel);
        String firstVideoLength = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@id='text'])[1]")).getText();
        System.out.println(firstVideoLength);
```

Response:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: (//span[@id='text'])[1]
```

Element snapshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To extract the ***duration of a YouTube*** video you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getText()`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer.style-scope.ytd-thumbnail span.style-scope.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer#text"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='thumbnail' and @href]//following::div[1]//span"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```