# Unable to get text values present within strong tag using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

While trying to print values present with in strong tag using xpath I'm getting following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: strong
```

This is my code :

```
WebElement eleText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong"));
String testerName = eleText.getText();
System.out.println(testerName);
```

This is my webpage which I'm trying to get values within strong tag :

```
 <a id="id_1099808326" class="activity"> 
    <strong>heizil</strong> : 
    <label id="check_label">  " First Device Test"
    </label>
    
    <a id="id_1099808296" class="activity"> 
    <strong>riya</strong>: 
    <label id=check_label"> " Second Device Test"
    </label>
```

**Expected output**: heizil,riya

If this is not the proper way can any one suggest any other way of getting the values present in `<strong>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the given HTML text ***heizil*** is within `<strong>` tag which is the immediate descendant of the `<a>` tag.

```
<a id="id_109996" class="activity"> 
    <strong>heizil</strong>
    : 
    <label id="sample_label">
        ...
        ...
    </label>
</a>
```

---

### Solution

To print the text ***heizil*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.activity > strong")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='activity']/strong")).getText());
  ```

---

Ideally, to extract the text value, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector* and `getText()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.activity > strong"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-link-normal' and @id='vvp-product-details-modal--product-title']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

Comment: thanks it really worked, had one more query on the same How can I locate an web element  and fetch them when I have multiple elements sharing the same class name

Comment: Like mentioned I need to fetch two names (Heizil and Riya), as I'm having same class sharing multiple element I'm only able to  get one name

Comment: @nayansFosgit Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question with all the relevant details. Will be happy to look in to the usecase.

Comment: have raised a new case kindly please look into it, thanks! 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75127045/how-to-fetch-multiple-text-values-present-within-strong-tag-when-there-is-multip

Comment: Thanks for the all the above help, it worked thanks!