# How to grab the result and assert that result is greater than 5000 using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, assertion

Which values do I have to put in actual and expected if that result is greater than 5000 and what can I do to print pass in the console?

Code trials:

```
public class Grabthe_result_google {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\l\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\chromedriver-win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).sendKeys("mobile",Keys.ENTER);
        String result = driver.findElement(By.id("result-stats")).getText().split(" ")[1];
     System.out.println(result);
    Assert.assertEquals(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, is this case you can use `assertTrue`.

Here is example of code:

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("APjFqb")).sendKeys("mobile",Keys.ENTER);
String result = driver.findElement(By.id("result-stats")).getText().split(" ")[1].replaceAll("," ,"");
Assert.assertTrue(Long.parseLong(result) > 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To assert if the number of search result value is more then ***5000***, you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and extract the text.
- Split the text with respect to the *blank* character and consider the second part.
- [Remove](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-remove-character-string) the `,` characters.
- Use `assertTrue()` from HardAssert after converting the *`string`* to *`long`* using [`parseLong()`](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-long-parselong-method)
- You can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q"))).sendKeys("mobile" +Keys.chord(Keys.RETURN));
  String result = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#result-stats"))).getText().split(" ")[1];
  System.out.println(result);
  String myresult = result.replace(",","");
  System.out.println(myresult);
  Assert.assertTrue(Long.parseLong(myresult) > 5000);
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  21,22,00,00,000
  21220000000
  ```