# How to capture screenshot of a WebElement within a webpage but not the entire screen or page through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ashot

I have to capture a screenshot of an image of a particular website. Maybe this is 20% off entire screen, I have used below code, it is capturing the entire screen. Which is not helping me to solve the problem.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

[image: Screenshot, what I want to do with selenium]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: How do I get the src of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245013/selenium-how-do-i-get-the-src-of-an-image)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[(text()='Stack Overflow') and @class='-img _glyph']"));
WrapsDriver wrapsDriver = (WrapsDriver) element;
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) wrapsDriver.getWrappedDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(element.getSize().width, element.getSize().height, element.getSize().height, element.getSize().width);
Point location = element.getLocation();
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
BufferedImage destImage = bufferedImage.getSubimage(location.x, location.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
ImageIO.write(destImage, "png", screenshot);
File file = new File("C:\\123.png");
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, file);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code trials `getScreenshotAs()` method will take the screenshot of the entire page.

To capture the screenshot of an *WebElement* within a particular webpage you can use the **`AShot()`** method importing **ashot-1.4.4.jar** while working with *Selenium Java Client v3.14.0*, *ChromeDriver v2.41*, *Chrome v 68.0*.

> **Note**: **`AShot()`** method from **ashot-1.4.4.jar** works only with [**jQuery**](https://jquery.com/) enabled *Web Applications*.

So as the website `http://www.google.com/` is not **jQuery** enabled **`AShot()`** method from **ashot-1.4.4.jar** won't be able to take the required screenshot.

As an example we will take a snapshot from the *website* `https://jquery.com/`.

- Code Block:

  ```
  package aShot;

  import java.io.File;

  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;

  public class ashot_google_homepage_logo {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          System.setProperty("god.bless.you", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://jquery.com/");
          WebElement myWebElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//h3[contains(.,'Lightweight Footprint')]")));
          Screenshot myScreenshot = new AShot().takeScreenshot(driver, myWebElement);
          ImageIO.write(myScreenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File("./Screenshots/elementScreenshot.png"));
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: elementScreenshot.png]

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to take screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/55120087#55120087)

Answer (score 0):

I am using selenium-java-3.141.59 and ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39, this code below works perfectly for me:

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  　driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
　　WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));
　　Screenshot screenshotHeader = new AShot().coordsProvider(new WebDriverCoordsProvider()).shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100)).takeScreenshot(driver, element);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(screenshotHeader.getImage(),"jpg",new　File("C:/TESTSELENIUM/Google.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```