# Selenium: java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster when using element size and location

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a code I took from [this](http://learn-selenium-easy.blogspot.com/2016/03/take-screenshot-of-specific-element-or-a-particular-div-using-selenium-web-driver-java.html) tutorial. It goes to a learn-selenium-easy.blogspot.com website, looks for Most Read/Popular Posts section and takes a picture of it:

```
 class SshotofElement {

    public static void screenShotElement() throws InterruptedException,IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        driver.get("http://learn-selenium-easy.blogspot.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Xpath of element to take screen shot
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='PopularPosts1']"));
        System.out.println(element.getSize());
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        // Take full screen screenshot
        BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
        Point point = element.getLocation();
        int elementWidth = element.getSize().getWidth();
        int elementHeight = element.getSize().getHeight();
        BufferedImage elementScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), elementWidth,elementHeight);  //exception here

        // crop the image to required
        ImageIO.write(elementScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("mostread_screenshot.png"));//path to save screen shot

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I get a `java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster` exception, however on line `BufferedImage elementScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), elementWidth,elementHeight);`. I'm not sure why it would be the case, since the points and size of the image are taken from the element itself.

Comment: This is quite possible scenario if your element is not currently within the screenshot. It may visually look to be there, but its bounding box will tell you do that. What you want do is put a check `elementWidth + X` <= Image width, if not then you need to truncate the same to avoid the exception

Comment: The targeted element is not visible in the viewport and `getScreenshotAs` captures the viewport only. Either call `((TakesScreenshot)element).getScreenshotAs(...);` or scroll the element into view and crop the screenshot from the location returned by `((Coordinates)element).inViewPort()`.

Comment: Oh I thought seleriom would solve all your problems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The element image you are cropping is not present in the screenshot taken by the code. If you put debug and print full screen shot path and manually view it then you can see desired element to be cropped from image is not present in it.
2. So first we need to **scroll page** to bring **desired element** into **view** and then take the screenshot. Then we need to crop the image based on element's location.
3. Also, `Point` class is not very reliable to give element's exact location.
4. Secondly if we see below values

   ```
   ImageIO.read(screenshot).getHeight() // ~ 943 => Total height
   element.getSize().getHeight() // ~ 511 => Element height 
   point.getY() // ~ 743 => start top side y coordinate of element
   ```
5. So I believe when rectangle is drawn from x,y with height of 743 it
   went out of original screenshot coordinates.

So we need to perform some adjustments while passing coordinates.

```
@Test
public void subImageTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    driver.get("http://learn-selenium-easy.blogspot.com/");
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,600)");
   File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='PopularPosts1']"));
    System.out.println(element.getSize());

  // Take full screen screenshot
    BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
    ImageIO.read(screenshot).getHeight()
    System.out.println(fullImg.getHeight()); 
    System.out.println(fullImg.getWidth());

    Point point = element.getLocation();
    int elementWidth = element.getSize().getWidth(); 
    int elementHeight = element.getSize().getHeight();

    // Now no exception here
    BufferedImage elementScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(220, 170,elementWidth+150,elementHeight+100);

    // crop the image to required
    ImageIO.write(elementScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\mostread_screenshot.png"));//path to save screen shot

}
```

Final sub image here of element after program executed
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### RasterFormatException

As per the *Java Docs* [RasterFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/RasterFormatException.html) is thrown if there is invalid layout information in the [Raster](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html).

---

### getLocation()

As per the *Selenium Documentation* [`getLocation()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getLocation--) returns the point containing the location of the **top left-hand corner** of the element.

---

### getSubimage()

As per the *Java Docs* [`getSubimage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) returns a subimage defined by a specified rectangular region. The returned BufferedImage shares the same data array as the original image and is defined as:

```
getSubimage
public BufferedImage getSubimage(int x,
                 int y,
                 int w,
                 int h)
Returns a subimage defined by a specified rectangular region. The returned BufferedImage shares the same data array as the original image.

Parameters: 
    x - the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region 
    y - the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region 
    w - the width of the specified rectangular region 
    h - the height of the specified rectangular region 

Returns: 
    a BufferedImage that is the subimage of this BufferedImage. 

Throws: 
    RasterFormatException - if the specified area is not contained within this BufferedImage.
```

---

I have taken your own code, added a couple of `System.out.println()` lines to showcase what exactly going wrong.

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class A_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
              System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
              ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
              options.addArguments("start-maximized");
              options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
              WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
              driver.get("http://learn-selenium-easy.blogspot.com/");
              // Xpath of element to take screen shot
              WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='PopularPosts1']"));
              System.out.println("Element size is:"+element.getSize());
              File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
              FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("./Screenshots/mostread_TakesScreenshot.png")); //path to save screen shot

              // Take full screen screenshot
              BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
              Point point = element.getLocation();
              System.out.println("Co-ordinates where on the page is the top left-hand corner of the rendered element:"+point);
              int elementWidth = element.getSize().getWidth();
              System.out.println("Element width is:"+elementWidth);
              int elementHeight = element.getSize().getHeight();
              System.out.println("Element height is:"+elementHeight);
              BufferedImage elementScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), elementWidth,elementHeight);  //exception here

              // crop the image to required
              ImageIO.write(elementScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
              FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("./Screenshots/mostread_BufferedImage.png"));//path to save screen shot
      }    
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  Element size is:(340, 486)
  Co-ordinates where on the page is the top left-hand corner of the rendered element:(104, 744)
  Element width is:340
  Element height is:486
  Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster
      at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
      at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
      at demo.A_demo.main(A_demo.java:78)
  ```

---

### Explanation

As discussed earlier, as per your code block `fullImg.getSubimage()` will try to return a `BufferedImage` i.e. **elementScreenshot** which will be a subimage defined by a specified by the rectangular region:

- x: the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region - `point.getX()` - **104**
- y: the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region - `point.getY()` - **744**
- w: the width of the specified rectangular region - elementWidth - **340**
- h: the height of the specified rectangular region - elementHeight - **486**

So, the expected height of the `BufferedImage` is turning out to be `744` + `486` = **`1230`** which is pretty much out of the *Raster*. Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

To take a screenshot of a specific element or a particular div using [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) and [java](/questions/tagged/java) you can use the **`AShot()`** method importing **ashot-1.4.4.jar** while working with *Selenium Java Client v3.14.0*, *ChromeDriver v2.41*, *Chrome v 68.0*.

> **Note**: **`AShot()`** method from **ashot-1.4.4.jar** works only with [**jQuery**](https://jquery.com/) enabled *Web Applications*.

- Code Block:

  ```
  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;

  public class A_demo 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("http://learn-selenium-easy.blogspot.com/");
          WebElement myWebElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='PopularPosts1']")));
          ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", myWebElement);
          Screenshot myScreenshot = new AShot().takeScreenshot(driver, myWebElement);
          ImageIO.write(myScreenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File("./Screenshots/elementAShotScreenshot.png"));
          driver.quit();
      }    
  }
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to capture screenshot of a WebElement within a webpage but not the entire screen or page through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015559/how-to-capture-screenshot-of-a-webelement-within-a-webpage-but-not-the-entire-sc/52054164#52054164)
- [Selenium: Not able to take complete page screenshot using aShot library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871748/selenium-not-able-to-take-complete-page-screenshot-using-ashot-library/50875676#50875676)

---

### Outro

You can find a detailed discussion of all the *Java* based methods of taking screenshot in [How to take screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/55120087#55120087)

Comment: Thank you for answering, Amit Jain was faster and his code doesn't include any other libraries, so I accepted his answer. I'll try to make up by upvoting some of your stuff. Or not...there's something weird about your reputation.